# How do I add a default vote value to every user for every post in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, express

real newbie in programming here. I started learning SQL a few days ago and now I am building a really simple backend in Express JS for a simple database that looks a little bit like the schema.

[image: schema]

There are users who can post posts and who can either upvote (+1) a post or downvote it (-1). With each vote, a record is added to the votes table. If the same user votes again on the same post, the vote will not be added, regardless if it is an upvote or a downvote. This is the query I am using for upvote, for example:

`INSERT INTO votes (username, post_id, vote) SELECT 'jackie' , 4, 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS  (SELECT * FROM votes WHERE username = 'jackie' AND post_id = 4);`

However, this is not really what I want because a user should be able to change their mind and downvote/upvote in case they voted differently. Therefore, I think it would be better if all the users had a default vote of 0 for each post, so I could rewrite the code for upvoting and downvoting as an UPDATE query instead.

Unfortunately, I am still not very good at SQL and I am not sure if it is even possible or how I would go about it. In my mind, it would look something like this even though it is obviously wrong and silly:

`INSERT INTO votes (username, post_id, vote) VALUES ('jackie', (SELECT id FROM posts), 0);`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: No don't have a "default" votes row, if a user never votes you will be storing redundant data, only insert a row if you need to and update it if it already exists.

Comment: Hello, there's some approaches that we could go, based on to the ERD:

1. It seems the relationship between  users <- vote (1..+), so the votes could be stored as historic / snapshot way; and hence, a "vote_date" Datetime field is required.

Comment: In this case, as the requirement says that "same user votes again on the same post, the vote will not be added", change the relationship as (1..1), adding a constrain in the FK post_id for avoiding duplicated and then CREATE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT data on "posts" table.